# Mongoose connect to authentication db syntax to include both auth and useNewUrlParser options

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to locally connect to an authentication db to access my app db. If I include the `useNewUrlParser: true` option it breaks the whole thing with an authentication failed. Removing the `useNewUrlParser` option connects but doesn't tick this option:

```
config = {
    database: "mongodb://localhost:27017/authapp",
    auth: {
        user : "admin",
        password : "123456",
        authdb : "admin"
    }

...

mongoose
  .connect(config.database, { 
        auth: config.auth,
        useNewUrlParser: true 
    })
  .then(() => {...}
```

I get:

> [nodemon] starting `node index.js` (node:17814) DeprecationWarning:
>   current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will
>   be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and
>   Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the
>   MongoClient constructor. App is running on 4000 {   database_error:
>   MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on
>   first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.
>         at Function._getError (/Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/scram.js:141:14)
>         at /Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/scram.js:191:31
>         at _callback (/Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:320:5)
>         at Connection.messageHandler (/Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:349:5)
>         at Connection.emit (events.js:321:20)
>         at processMessage (/Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:384:10)
>         at Socket. (/Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:553:15)
>         at Socket.emit (events.js:321:20)
>         at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:305:12)
>         at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:280:11)
>         at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
>         at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
>       name: 'MongoError',
>       [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}   }]
>         at Pool. (/Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:433:11)
>         at Pool.emit (events.js:321:20)
>         at /Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:577:14
>         at /Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1007:11
>         at callback (/Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:93:5)
>         at /Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:367:21
>         at /Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/auth_provider.js:66:11
>         at /Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/scram.js:193:16
>         at _callback (/Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:320:5)
>         at Connection.messageHandler (/Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:349:5)
>         at Connection.emit (events.js:321:20)
>         at processMessage (/Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:384:10)
>         at Socket. (/Users/bpav/vue/new_app/authapp/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:553:15)
>         at Socket.emit (events.js:321:20)
>         at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:305:12)
>         at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:280:11) {
>       name: 'MongoNetworkError',
>       [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}   } }

Is there a pattern that I am missing or what is a way that works for this case? I also tried the user+pw in the db connection string but it doesn't connect as expected either - maybe missing the authentication db name?

Hope someone can point me in the right direction for this simple issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use authSource instead of authdb

```
 auth:{
     user: "admin",
     password: "123456",
     authSource: "admin",                                 
    },
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to contain an explanation? Why authSource?